# Tomcat does not connect to the database, but when I run it from within netbeans works perfectly

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using Java + BlazeDS + MySQL + Flash Builder + EclipseLink (JPA 2.1) + Tomcat 7 (Windows)

The problem is this, when I compile my application within Netbeans the connection to the database works perfectly. But when I do a deploy directly in tomcat with war file it does not access the database.

I tried with multiple versions of tomcat, including tomcat netbeans and it did not work. Only works when I run the project from within Netbeans

I'm almost mad trying to solve it, someone has gone through this problem?

I really appreciate any help

My persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="goncricPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>    
<class>entidade.sancric</class>
<class>entidade.logincric</class>    
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/derea?   zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="qwaszx"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="derea"/>
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

.......

File that makes the persistence in database:

```
 */
public class persistir {
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("goncricPU");

public void persist(Object object) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(object);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
           Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught",   e);
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
   }   

}
```

Comment: What is the error message when deployed in tomcat?

Comment: Do you get some exception in tomcat logs?

Comment: There is absolutely no error message in tomcat.

The tomcat loads my application perfectly, just does not connect to the database. the connection with the database occurs only when run from within netbeans

Comment: Please show the code: You possibly just do not log the exception. How do you connect? Connection pool? Which database? Tomcat has access to the JDBC driver? JDBC URL?

Comment: beryllium Hello, thank you for your attention. Added JDBC (C: \ apache-tomcat-7.0.42 \ lib \ mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar) . I'm not using connection pool and also do not use JNDI The configuration with the database is in my persistence.xml file

Comment: Problem solved!

My friends, after some time suffering, the problem was solved in a very simple way.

Just added the environment variables (Path) the lib folder of my application
C: \ apache-tomcat-7.0.42 \ webapps \ dereaasc \ WEB-INF \ lib

And everything worked perfectly!

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm always suspicious when I see "perfectly" and "absolutely" and "no messages".

I would treat any behavior you get out of NetBeans as the red herring.  It's an IDE and won't be part of your production deployment.  You'll make progress faster if you leave NetBeans out of your thinking.

My first guess is that you don't have the MySQL JDBC connector JAR in the Tomcat /lib folder.  Tomcat 7 demands that it find that JDBC driver JAR there and nowhere else.  If you have it in your WAR file, I'd suggest that you move it out of the application package and onto the app server.

Are you using a connection pool?  Any JNDI resources?  Do you have log4j configured in your app?  Any frameworks like Spring?

You've provided no other information, so that informed guess will have to do until you can tell us more.

Comment: duffymo Hello, thank you for your attention. Added JDBC (C: \ apache-tomcat-7.0.42 \ lib \ mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar) also removed from inside the war and tried, but without success.

I'm not using connection pool and also do not use JNDI

The configuration with the database is in my persistence.xml file


can be something that is missing in my environment variables?

Comment: Could be.  I don't know how your Java code acquires the JDBC connection.

Comment: Posted the persistence.xml file and the file that makes the persistence of the object in the database.

Comment: So you're doing JPA.  I'm guessing that you failed to set up a JNDI connection factory properly.  The Tomcat 7 doc pages show you how.  Try that.

Comment: Problem solved!

My friends, after some time suffering, the problem was solved in a very simple way.

Just added the environment variables (Path) the lib folder of my application
C: \ apache-tomcat-7.0.42 \ webapps \ dereaasc \ WEB-INF \ lib

And everything worked perfectly!

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: I agree, it sure must have an explanation and most appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

After some time suffering, the problem was solved in a very simple way.

Just added the environment variables (Path) the lib folder of my application

```
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\dereaasc\WEB-INF\lib
```

And everything worked perfectly!